# Need Concept to create a function using array or whatever you suggest- in sql server

Tags: t-sql, excel, vba

Below is the example of Data.

```
ss-tt(1/21/2014  9:47:12 AM)->bb-tt-uu(02/07/14 11:09:59)
```

Above data is store in a column of a table. Now what I want to do ,to split "date" which is followed by "ss-tt" and paste it in another column but in same row.

For that i want to create a function in Sql server. It is quite easy in excel(VBA) to create  a function using array but in Sql server i don't understand how to use the array concept.

Below is the function which i had created in excel(VBA) for the same calculation.

```
    Sub readExcell1()

     Dim arr() As Variant
     Dim token As Variant
     Dim innertoken As Variant
     Dim first As String
     Dim second As String
     Dim ind As Integer


     arr = Range("D2:D849")
     Dim R As Long
    Dim C As Long
    rownum = 1
    colnum = 1
    For R = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) ' First array dimension is rows.
        'MsgBox "processing row " & R
        'MsgBox arr(R, 1)


        token = Split(arr(R, 1), "->")

        For i = LBound(token) To UBound(token)
            'MsgBox token(i)
            innertoken = Split(token(i), "(")
            first = innertoken(0)
            first = Trim(first)
            second = innertoken(1)
            If first = "payroll-apac" Then
                ind = 1 + R
                second = Replace(Trim(second), ")", "")
                Application.Range("H" & ind).Value = second
                GoTo Label1
            End If

        Next i
Label1:
    Next R


End Sub
```

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want. Obviously you could handle the prefix and separator separately rather than use columns.

```
declare @table table (
[value]       [nvarchar](max)
, [prefix]    [sysname]
, [separator] [sysname]
, [calculated] as substring([value]
             , len([prefix]) + 1
             , charindex([separator]
                         , [value]) - len([prefix]) - 1));
--
insert into @table
        ([value]
         , [prefix]
         , [separator])
values      (N'ss-tt(1/21/2014 9:47:12 AM)->bb-tt-uu(02/07/14 11:09:59)'
         , N'ss-tt('
         , N')');
--
select [value]
   , [calculated]
from   @table;
```